# How has Google managed to keep com.android.internal.R hidden?

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am stumped. I checked the source both in the SDK folder and github and no sign of it. From other answers it is clear to me that they want to hide that from the public because of the changes that might happen in that or any internal class for that matter. So, my question shouldn't be interpreted around, "Why do I need to access that in the first place?"

I can go by without looking at that code but the question is that when the R class is not available in the sources, how come Android Studio is compiling the code referencing it?

Also, there is no library in Java where you can't ultimately peek the source code so how has Google managed to do it?

For that matter, I also tried to import a fictitious package and class and it didn't compile as expected.

Comment: R.java is generated automatically by Android Studio. If you even delete that file it will be generated again

Comment: Agreed. So long as the `R` class is there at compile time, it is not needed in a version control system. In fact, `R` is not normally stored in a version control system, even with ordinary apps. Why would you expect their `R` to be in version control, or in source archives culled from version control?

Comment: @CommonsWare : But there are other classes too that are available on the Android Github repository but not in the Android SDK directory. For ex: android.annotation.StyleableRes. I mean, how does Android Studio know of their presence without the .class file?

Comment: Android Studio has the `.class` file. `android.annotation.StyleableRes` is in the `support-annotations` library.

Comment: @VivekMishra : R.java is generated by Android Studio by not the com.android.internal.R.class because there is reference to the constant inside this class with a fixed value 0 and that can't happen if Android Studio automatically generates it with varying constants.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Okay, agreed. I got confused because of the android's framework and myself looking in the framework for it but see my comment to Vivek Mishra

Comment: I do not know what "there is reference to the constant inside this class with a fixed value 0" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare : There is a reference in FrameLayout.java - R.styleable.FrameLayout_Layout_layout_gravity. When I search R.styleable, docs show this constant's value as 0 but since this constant is inside R.java and since the file is supposed to be automatically generated, how can we rely on this constant value?

Comment: `R.styleable` != `com.android.internal.R`. The `R` classes **in the Android SDK** have fixed values. I forget the mechanism by which they ensure that. But `com.android.internal.R` is not part of the Android SDK, and AFAIK its values can vary.

Comment: @CommonsWare : I am very confused with the whole thing - When I hover over the expression R.styleable.FrameLayout_Layout_layout_gravity, it shows me large negative number then I follow the call in which it is passed. In the call, the debugger is showing me the passed value "0". How could the passed value have been different from the one received. I then searched it on the docs and R.styleable which showed it to be 0. I also checked the import statements and it is android.internal.R that gets imported and R.styleable doesn't exist in any other R.java file.

Comment: "I am very confused with the whole thing" -- that's why I usually ignore them. So long as they work, I am not complaining.